# js more then one Value not gate from out side in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, call

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var my_site = 'katzbb.com';
var ex_domains = "['phaze.co'],['katzddl.org']";
</script>
```

and in the URL: i will add 
   http://***/pcloud.php
These Code & call the url like .js

```
var exclude_domains = [['lx5.in'],['backlink.lx5.in'],ex_domains,[my_site]];
```

What i'm doing wrong  i need to print ex_domains value ['phaze.co'],['katzddl.org']
pleas help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you want ?

```
var my_site = 'katzbb.com';
var ex_domains = ['phaze.co','katzddl.org'];
var exclude_domains = ['lx5.in','backlink.lx5.in'];

var excluded = exclude_domains.concat(ex_domains,my_site);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QLaxC/